# I want to add an attribute to a class that other classes of the same name are not affected

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7RhD.png) html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJwK9.png) css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN4vD.png) javascript
I want only one element to get the attribute and not affect the others

Comment: please can you transcribe the content of those pictures in text?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`

```
document.querySelector('my-class').classList.toggle('the-only-one')
```